# Serialization changes the attribute value when using &lt; or &gt; ('<' or '>')

Tags: c#, xml, serialization, xsd, deserialization

Given the following piece of xml code:

```
<SD GID="&lt;empty&gt;" T="2017-07-31T13:37:48Z">&lt;empty&gt;</SD>
```

From an xsd file i generated classes with xsd.exe and the corresponding class for deserializing/serializing this element is the following:

```
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("xsd", "4.0.30319.33440")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(Namespace="http://autosar.org/schema/r4.0")]
public partial class SD {
    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute(DataType = "NMTOKEN")]
    public string GID;

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
    public string S;

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
    public string T;

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTextAttribute()]
    public string Value;
}
```

As it can be seen on the following picture this line was well deserialized, the '<' and '>' characters were decoded properly:
[Quickwatch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V0wyq.jpg)

I only would like to serialize back the without changing the content, but this line line translated back to the following way:

```
<SD GID="_x003C_empty_x003E_" T="2017-07-31T13:37:48Z">&lt;empty&gt;</SD>
```

So in the value field there is the correct string, according to the xml standard, but in the GID attribute the '<' and '>' are not translated properly.

The main code is very simple:

```
namespace MyXMLHandler
{
    using System;
    using System.IO;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Xml;
    using System.Xml.Serialization;

    internal class Program
    {
        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            MyType a = DeserializeObject(
                @"source.arxml");
            SerializeObject(
                @"source_SERIALIZED.arxml",
                a);
        }

        private static MyType DeserializeObject(string filename)
        {
            var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(MyType));
            XmlReaderSettings xmlReaderSettings = new XmlReaderSettings();
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(filename, Encoding.UTF8);
            MyType i;

            i = (MyType)serializer.Deserialize(reader);

            return i;
        }

        private static void SerializeObject(string filename, MyType i)
        {
            var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(MyType));
            Stream fs = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Create);
            var settings = new XmlWriterSettings();
            settings.Indent = true;
            settings.IndentChars = "    ";
            settings.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8;
            var writer = XmlWriter.Create(fs, settings);

            serializer.Serialize(writer, i);

            writer.Close();

        }
    }
}
```

What can be the reason of the wrong translation of those charachters in the attribute?

Comment: No, it is'nt marked.

Comment: If you'll remove `DataType = "NMTOKEN"` the problem will be solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An NMTOKEN cannot validly contain `<` or `>` (even if these are escaped as character references), so the serializer has found its own way to convert the attribute value to a valid NMTOKEN.

Comment: In XML file (Java and DOM Parser), "&lt;" is present as node text value but when node.getContentType is used for this node then this is converted to "<". Is there anyway to retrieve "&lt;" itself, instead of  "<"?

Comment: And for those of us that does not have NMTOKEN specified in the code, what do we do?

Comment: You ask a new question, describing your problem from first principles, rather than making a comment on an answer to a different question asked over 2 years ago.